# how to import multiple sql file in android db using jquery

Tags: android, jquery

I have multiple sql file in my assets folder and building app on android. I want this sql to import in android app database on by one using jquery. How to do that please help. I have done code for single file but i want it for multiple sql file.

```
var filePath = 'database/crmaaaa_1.sql';
            //alert(filePath);
            $.get(filePath, function (response) {
                 var statements = response.split('\n');

                 var shortName = "crm1";
                 var version = '1.0';
                 var displayName = 'crm1';
                 var maxSize = 40000000; //  bytes
                // db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
                 var db = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
                // db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB);
                 db.transaction(function (transaction) {
                    jQuery.each(statements, function (index, value) {
                    //  alert("query"+value);
                        if (value != '') {
                            transaction.executeSql(value, [], successHandler, function (e) {
                                alert("Error executing sql " + value);
                            });
                        }

                    });
                 });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of sql files to import:

```
 var sqlFiles = ['file1.sql', 'file2.sql', 'file3.sql'];

 $(sqlFiles).each(function() {
     $.get(this, function (response) {
          // your sql file management
          // ...
     }
 });
```

This should get you to the goal.